# Arithmetic calculation for BODMAS in Java

Tags: java

I have written this code for Bodmas, but getting some error in this. If I do 3-5+9, it will result in 3.04.0.

It just start concatenating, though it works for all other operations like *, / and -, please help.

```
public static String calculation(BODMASCalculation bodmas, String result) {
    while (bodmas.hasMatch()) {
        double value, leftOfOperator = bodmas.getLeft();
        char op = bodmas.getOperator();
        double rightOfOprator = bodmas.getRight();

        switch (op) {
        case '/':
            if(rightOfOprator == 0) //Divide by 0 generates Infinity
                value = 0;
            else
                value = leftOfOperator / rightOfOprator;
            break;
        case '*':
            value = leftOfOperator * rightOfOprator;
            break;
        case '+':
            value = leftOfOperator + rightOfOprator;
            break;
        case '-':
            value = leftOfOperator - rightOfOprator;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator.");
        }           
        result = result.substring(0, bodmas.getStart()) + value + result.substring(bodmas.getEnd());
        bodmas = new BODMASCalculation(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Another function is:-

```
public boolean getMatchFor(String text, char operator) {
    String regex = "(-?[\\d\\.]+)(\\x)(-?[\\d\\.]+)";
    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex.replace('x', operator)).matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        this.leftOfOperator = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
        this.op = matcher.group(2).charAt(0);
        this.rightOfOprator = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(3));
        this.start = matcher.start();
        this.end = matcher.end();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a solution by adding

```
String sss = null;
        if(op == '+' && !Str.isBlank(result.substring(0, bodmas.getStart())) && value >= 0)
            sss = "+";
        else
            sss = "";
        result = result.substring(0, bodmas.getStart()) + sss + value   + result.substring(bodmas.getEnd());
```

But don't want to do that, I want this to work for all the operators.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? If so, what did you learn from using it?

Comment: Yes I did, i can fix that but it won't be generic. So i need a generic one.

Comment: Fix what? And what do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: Code that will work for all the Arithmetic operations.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It's pretty much unreadable.

Comment: You don't. Update your question.

Comment: Since you have a working code, but want to improve the quality of code, you can try [codereview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi Payeli, I can't do that in code. it will fail for others.

Comment: Throw it all away and look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm, or recursive descent expression parsing. You will never implement operator predecence or parentheses with this code as a basis.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class EvaluateString
{
    public static int evaluate(String expression)
    {
        char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();

         // Stack for numbers: 'values'
        Stack<Integer> values = new Stack<Integer>();

        // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
        Stack<Character> ops = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
             // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
            if (tokens[i] == ' ')
                continue;

            // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
            if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
            {
                StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
                // There may be more than one digits in number
                while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9')
                    sbuf.append(tokens[i++]);
                values.push(Integer.parseInt(sbuf.toString()));
            }

            // Current token is an opening brace, push it to 'ops'
            else if (tokens[i] == '(')
                ops.push(tokens[i]);

            // Closing brace encountered, solve entire brace
            else if (tokens[i] == ')')
            {
                while (ops.peek() != '(')
                  values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));
                ops.pop();
            }

            // Current token is an operator.
            else if (tokens[i] == '+' || tokens[i] == '-' ||
                     tokens[i] == '*' || tokens[i] == '/')
            {
                // While top of 'ops' has same or greater precedence to current
                // token, which is an operator. Apply operator on top of 'ops'
                // to top two elements in values stack
                while (!ops.empty() && hasPrecedence(tokens[i], ops.peek()))
                  values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));

                // Push current token to 'ops'.
                ops.push(tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        // Entire expression has been parsed at this point, apply remaining
        // ops to remaining values
        while (!ops.empty())
            values.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), values.pop(), values.pop()));

        // Top of 'values' contains result, return it
        return values.pop();
    }

    // Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
    // otherwise returns false.
    public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
    {
        if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
            return false;
        if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    // A utility method to apply an operator 'op' on operands 'a' 
    // and 'b'. Return the result.
    public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new
                UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return a / b;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Driver method to test above methods
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(EvaluateString.evaluate("10 + 2 * 6"));
        System.out.println(EvaluateString.evaluate("100 * 2 + 12"));
        System.out.println(EvaluateString.evaluate("100 * ( 2 + 12 )"));
        System.out.println(EvaluateString.evaluate("100 * ( 2 + 12 ) / 14"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also add some explanation for your answers. Just code alone does not explain anything and is considered low-quality. Please look at [answer] and [edit] your answer.

Comment: This *is* the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. You should certainly have said so, and you should have explained how and why this solves the problem.

Comment: Also this does not handle the cases of negative input such as ("-4 * -4")

Answer (score 1):

The Java Scripting API allows you to pass parameters from Java application to the script engine and vice versa.

You can use Javax ScriptEngine to pass values from your app to a script.

And using it's `eval()` method, you can give it a mathematical expression in the form of a string and it will do the the math for you... (Handles BODMAS too).

*Example:*

```
     ScriptEngineManager mgr = new.ScriptEngineManager();
     ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
     String foo = "40+2/3*45";
     System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
```

**Outputs:** *70*

Include the following imports , if the IDE doesn't suggest them :

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

Check the documentation here [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be achieved by using the shunting yard algorithm. We start by creating an infix notation of the equation then follows the postfix notation. Here is a description of the algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm. This solution solves for any nested number of brackets on the string expression.

```
  public static double evaluate(String exp) {
    char[] tokens = exp.toCharArray();

    Queue<Object> values = new LinkedList<>();
    // Stack for Operators: 'ops'
    Stack<Character> ops = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        //infix
        // Current token is a whitespace, skip it
        if (tokens[i] == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        // Current token is a number, push it to stack for numbers
        else if (tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9') {
            StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
            // There may be more than one digits in number

            while (i < tokens.length && tokens[i] >= '0' && tokens[i] <= '9') {
                sbuf.append(tokens[i]);
                if ((i+1)<tokens.length &&tokens[i + 1] >= '0' && tokens[i + 1] <= '9') {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            values.add(Double.parseDouble(sbuf.toString()));
        } else if (tokens[i] == '*' || tokens[i] == '-' || tokens[i] == '/' || tokens[i] == '+') {
            if (ops.isEmpty()) {
                ops.push(tokens[i]);
                continue;
            }
            char op1 = ops.peek();
            boolean hasHighPrecedence = hasPrecedence(op1, tokens[i]);
            if (hasHighPrecedence) {
                char op = ops.pop();
                values.add(op);
                ops.push(tokens[i]);
            } else {
                ops.push(tokens[i]);
            }
        } else if (tokens[i] == '(') {
            ops.push(tokens[i]);
        } else if (tokens[i] == ')') {
            while (ops.peek() != '(') {
                values.add(ops.pop());
            }
            ops.pop();
        }
    }
    while (!ops.isEmpty()) {
        values.add(ops.pop());
    }
    //post fix
    Stack<Double> numStack = new Stack<>();
    while (!values.isEmpty()) {
        Object val = values.poll();
        if (val instanceof Character) {
            char v = (Character) val;
            if (v == '*' || v == '-' || v == '/' || v == '+') {
                double num2, num1;
                num1 = numStack.pop();
                num2 = numStack.pop();
                double ans = applyOp(v, num1, num2);
                numStack.push(ans);

            }
        } else {
            double num = (double) val;
            numStack.push(num);
        }
    }
    return numStack.pop();

}

public static double applyOp(char op, double b, double a) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new
                        IllegalArgumentException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return a / b;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2) {
    if (op1 == '*' && op2 == '/') {
        return false;
    } else if (op1 == '/' && op2 == '*') {
        return true;
    } else if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-')) {
        return true;
    } else if (op1 == '+' && op2 == '-') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"BODMAS" is a not very operational rule. Especially addition and subtraction have the same precedence and are calculated from left to right 1-2+3-4+5 = (((1-2)+3)-4)+5.

The rule is for a nested loop.

Loop

1. replaceAll `(` number `)` --> number
2. replaceAll number `[*/]' number --> number op number
3. replaceAll number `[+-]' number --> number op number

Until nothing is replaced.

This ensures that 3-4/2*6+5 -2-> 3-2*6+5 -2-> 3-12+5 -3-> -9+5 -3-> -4